# Number format in column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Is there a fast formula to change a column number to dollars. Example my data is set to general and it is says 2199 but it should be 21.99. Is there  fast formula to update this.

I am not finding an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is about number format, but the sample data in your question is about two different values.

The number **format** only changes how the number is displayed, but it does not change the underlying value.

If you want to convert the number 2199 to 21.99, you need to divide it by 100

=A1/100

If you have an existing list of numbers that you want to quickly convert, do this:

- in an empty cell type the value 100
- copy the cell
- select all the cells containing the numbers you want to convert
- open the Paste Special dialog (Home ribbon > Paste dropdown > Paste Special)
- tick the option **Divide** under Operations and click OK

[image]

After that, you can use a **format** that uses $ signs, for e.g. the built-in "Accounting"  format or any format of your choice.

If you want any number that is typed into a cell to be treated as if the last 2 digits of the number were decimals, you can use a setting in **Excel Options > Advanced > Automatically insert a decimal point**.

Then you can type `2199` and one you hit enter the cell value will be 21.99. That also means that if you want a value of 22.00, you must type `2200`.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.